# Access Denied When Updating Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When updating Conda, I am getting the below error:

> Preparing transaction: done
>   Verifying transaction: done
>   Executing transaction: failed
>   ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
>   PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
>   Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')

Comment: try to update in 'run as administrator'

Comment: if this is the solution for your answer, please press the tick button in below-written answer and it will be marked as the solution for your question :)

Comment: yes... Gino Mempin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try to update in 'run as administrator'**